# Periodical background 'git status' in Git Extensions interferes with interactive work

Tags: git, git-extensions

I use Git Extensions and command line simultaneously (I use git-tfs, so should use command line for push/fetch).

But if I try push changes from command line with not closed Git Extensions window, it often finish with error

`fatal: Unable to create '.git/index.lock': File exists.`

reason obvious - Git Extensions periodically execute git status which create lock file and prevent push.

I found solution - close Git Extensions before work in console, but it not very handy and I often forgot it.

What else can I do here? May be somehow disable create lock for git status?

Answer (score 1):

Git 2.14 proposes already a background refresh for `git status`, that **[Git Extensions](http://gitextensions.github.io/)** might end up benefiting from:

See [commit 5e83cca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e83cca0b83b4a915f9ed246c2bcfeeb5a58b86b) (27 Nov 2017) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e6bf6af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6bf6afe27d9a600963e8733ce17e7b067a4701c), 13 Dec 2017)</sup>

> `git-status.txt`: mention **`--no-optional-locks`**
>
> If you come to the documentation thinking "I do not want Git to take any locks for my background processes", then you may easily run across "`--no-optional-locks`" in `git.txt`.
>
> But it's quite reasonable to hit a specific instance of the problem: you have "`git status`" running in the background, and you notice that it causes lock contention with other processes. So you look in `git-status.txt` to see if there is a way to disable it, but there's no mention of the flag.
>
> Let's add a short note mentioning that status does indeed
>   touch the index (and why), with a pointer to the global option. That can point users in the right direction and help them make a more informed decision about what they're disabling.

So the [`git status` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5e83cca0b83b4a915f9ed246c2bcfeeb5a58b86b/Documentation/git-status.txt#L369-L380) now reads:

> ### BACKGROUND REFRESH
>
> By default, `git status` will automatically refresh the index, updating
>   the cached stat information from the working tree and writing out the
>   result.
>   **Writing out the updated index is an optimization that isn't
>   strictly necessary** (`status` computes the values for itself, but writing
>   them out is just to save subsequent programs from repeating our
>   computation).
>   When `status` is run in the background, the lock held during the write may conflict with other simultaneous processes, causing them to fail.
>   **Scripts running `status` in the background should consider
>   using `git --no-optional-locks status`.**

If that last sentence could find its way in the embedded Git packaged in Git Extensions, that would solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

While the issue is caused by `git status` locking, it can *also* be mitigated with a setting change from Git Extensions *without* needing to close Git Extensions before opting to perform Git work elsewhere: I do most of my work from "elsewhere" so closing Git Extensions is not a fun long-term strategy :}

From [twinsec](https://github.com/twinsec) on  https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1044 -

> For anyone ran into the same issue with index lock, there's a workaround [by]
>
> - ***disabling** Settings -> Git Extensions -> Performance -> Show number of changed files*
>
> [..] so that Git Extensions *won't* call git status as soon as any file updates which [is] blocking the current processing git commands and introducing the lock.
>
> Hope this help for you guys.